# asp.net web forms unit test parsing xml test returned collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, unit-testing

I have a web forms application that parses some xml and returns a collection. I use a utitily class that parses the xml. Im trying to write a unit test to check the returned collection of objects. heres my code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Web_Application.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _Web_Application.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        string source = @"C:\Users\F\Desktop\Web Application\Web    Application.Tests\LunchTest.xml";

        [TestMethod]
        public void ParseXml()
        {
            XmlUlitilyClass x = new XmlUlitilyClass();
            x.ParseXml(source);

            Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source).Last(), 4);
            Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source).Last().Name, "Roast of the day");
            Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source).Last().DesertIncluded, true);
        }
    }
}
```

is the correct way to do this or am i way off thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a good approach.  My only concern is the source file `@"C:\Users\F\Desktop\Web Application\Web    Application.Tests\LunchTest.xml";` must be on every machine that runs the test.

Does `XmlUlitilyClass` accept a XML string instead of filename?  If so pass it the contents of `LunchTest.xml`.

Comment: im getting a error through im not referencing ulility class properly

Comment: Error 30 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Francis_Gallagher_Web_Application.Models.Lunch>' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<_Web_Application.Models.Lunch>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Francis\Desktop\Francis Gallagher Web Application\Web Application.Tests\UnitTest1.cs 23 48Web Application.Tests